# converting string to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a problem regarding data conversion using R language.

I have two data that being stored in variables named lung.X and lung.y, below are the description of my data.

```
> str(lung.X)
 chr [1:86, 1:7129] "  170.0" "  104.0" "   53.7" "  119.0" "  105.5" "  130.0" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:86] "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:7129] "A28102_at" "AB000114_at" "AB000115_at" "AB000220_at" ...
```

and

```
> str(lung.y)
 num [1:86] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
```

`lung.X` is a matrix (row: 86 col: 7129) and `lung.y` is an array of numbers (86 entries)

Do anyone know how to convert above data into the format below?

```
> str(lung.X)
     num [1:86, 1:7129] 170 104 53.7 119 105.5 130...
```

I thought I should do like this

```
lung.X <- as.numeric(lung.X)
```

but I got this instead

```
> str(lung.X)
 num [1:613094] 170 104 53.7 119 105.5 130...
```

The reason of doing this is because I need `lung.X` to be numerical only.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `lung.X[] <- as.numeric(lung.X)` or `mode(lung.X) <- "numeric"`.

Comment: Just add the dimensions attribute back, e.g. `dim(lung.X) <- c(86,7129)`

Comment: @sgibb, the first one does not function but the second one is working! Thank you.

Comment: @joran, yours is also working! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try: `m <- matrix(as.numeric(lung.X), nrow = 86, ncol = 7129)`

If you need it in dataframe/list format, `df <- data.frame(m)`

Comment: No problem, Rafidah.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `mode` of your `matrix` to `numeric`:

```
## example data
m <- matrix(as.character(1:10), nrow=2,
            dimnames = list(c("R1", "R2"), LETTERS[1:5]))
m
#    A   B   C   D   E
# R1 "1" "3" "5" "7" "9"
# R2 "2" "4" "6" "8" "10"

str(m)
#  num [1:2, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "R1" "R2"
#   ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
# NULL

mode(m) <- "numeric"
str(m)
#  num [1:2, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "R1" "R2"
#   ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
# NULL
m
#    A B C D  E
# R1 1 3 5 7  9
# R2 2 4 6 8 10
```